# Getting bandwidth spent by user or by rails application on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bandwidth, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm running multiple rails applications on `AWS` instance and I need to know how many bandwidth is each application using/wasting.

Some of the applications are running with `passenger` over `Apache2` some of them are running over `Passenger standalone` server and some of them are running on `WebRick standalone` server.

Also each application is located under a corresponding home user directory, because we've created a user for each project.

Now, can I get the bandwidth usage for each user and log it to text files o even directly to my database?

Or can I get the bandwidth usage for each Ruby on Rails application running?

I have already used the `iptraf` command line utility but it was on one sever hosting one single rails application and just got to log the traffic on one interface, now I need to have the usage by user or by application.

Any help?

Thanks.